# RX and Model-View-Presenter in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, system.reactive, mvp, scheduler

I am new to RX and I'm trying to adapt it to my WinForms application.
(Un?)fortunately I use MVP pattern where the View is abstracted from any specific implementation (e.g. WinForms).

When RX-friendly Model produces new value, presenter gets it and tries to update the view. The problem is that I cannot observe on the main thread since I have no reference to WinForms Control.

I found a few solutions but neither of them looks well to me:

1. Create a Control property in the view so that I could observe on it.
2. Use Control.Invoke inside property setters which are modified by the Presenter
3. Create an extension method similar to:

:

```
public static IObservable<T> ObserveOn<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, IMyView view)
{
    var control = (Control)view;
    return observable.ObserveOn(control);
}
```

Is there a nice way to handle this?

**EDIT:** I found another solution which I like the most:

```
private readonly SynchronizationContext _syncContext;

public Presenter()
{
    _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current; //I can observe on this one with a reasonable assumption that presenter is created on the UI thread
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the presenter running on the UI thread at the time that it subscribes to the model?  Just use [ObserveOnDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211843%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) at the time your present subscribes to the observable:

```
// from your presenter code, which is running on the UI thread:
model.ObservableProperty.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(p => updateView(p));
```

Edit:

Alternatively, you can get `Rx-Windows Forms Helper` and have your `IMyView` interface expose an `IScheduler` (which it creates by calling `new ControlScheduler(control)`).

Then you can implement your `ObserveOn(observable, view)` extension method as:

```
public static IObservable<T> ObserveOn<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, IMyView view)
{
    return observable.ObserveOn(view.Scheduler);
}
```

Comment: Which NuGet package contains the extension method? I can't find it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure.  I think `Rx-WPF`, though I think you only need to reference `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll`.

Comment: "view.Scheduler" solution seems good. However I found another approach (see Edit). What do you think of it?

Comment: yeah that is yet another way :)